# problem of denied access using kvm

Tags: users, opensuse, kvm, access-control

I would like to test kvm with opensuse tumbleweed.
I successfully installed kvm, but I am stuck in creating my first VM.

The trick is that I want to have the VM's directory in an external HDD.

When I set the directory of the VM file I get this error message:

> Impossible de terminer l'installation : « Cannot access storage file
>   '/run/media/lowley/424b7b47-883d-42ac-b6f3-994c0c01c01f/sauvegardes/fedora-haskell.qcow2'
>   (as uid:471, gid:10): Permission denied »

I am not very strong in managing user rights. I set root belong to the kvm group, but I still have this error.

can you help me?

thank you

olivier

EDIT

I launch it by a entering `virt-manager`, as me and not as root. 
In fact I have a shortcut on the desktop.

Comment: are you using libvirt (e.g. with `virsh` or `virt-manager`) or running `kvm` or  `qemu-system-$architecture` directly? please edit your question and add the actual command you used to run your VM (use the `{}` icon in the editor to format it as code).

Comment: are you in the libvirt group?  do you have RW access to the `.../fedora-haskell.qcow2` file?  Have you created a libvirt storage pool for `/run/media/lowley/424b7b47-883d-42ac-b6f3-994c0c01c01f/sauvegardes/`?  does the libvirt user and/or group have access to that directory?

Comment: Now I'm in the libvirt group. Moreover, the qcow2 file, its containing directory and the drive are "777" using chmod. But it doesn't work. Virt-manager is complaining about search rights missing for the qcow2 file. But it works when I launch virt-manager with sudo. I would prefer to avoid this...

Comment: indeed, with sudo I have to type the statement manually, I can't make a shortcut. have you got another suggestion?

Comment: the only thing i can suggest is to try creating a small VM (install freedos on it, perhaps) in the standard, default storage pool provided by the libvirt package on opensuse.  If that works, you need to set up the permissions on the USB drive directory & qcow2 file the same as in /var/lib/libvirt/images (or wherever opensuse's default pool is, find with `virsh pool-dumpxml default | grep path`).

Comment: one other thing - the VM disk images, have to be in the libvirt group AND RW by group (`chmod g+rw`) for you to be able to use them under your UID.  Also, if you haven't logged out and logged back in again since adding yourself to the libvirt group, you should do so.

Answer (score 0):

Did it! 
You were right: I needed to change file permissions, for the directories and the qcow2 file, the correct user was qemu and the group wheel. Thank you!